# Facing issue when running xbuild after building mono via meta-mono version 6.12.0.161

Tags: mono, metaprogramming, yocto, yocto-recipe, xbuild

I am trying to do build in an yocto environment where I am using meta-mono version 6.12.0.161(latest from [kirkstone branch](https://github.com/DynamicDevices/meta-mono/tree/kirkstone)). But after this, during build, when I am trying to run xbuild, its not working properly. Even a simple "xbuild /version" command is not giving any input.

I am using the [recipe 6.12.0.161.bb file](https://github.com/DynamicDevices/meta-mono/blob/kirkstone/recipes-mono/mono/mono-native_6.12.0.161.bb) for my build.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ The mission of Mono is likely to be ended in less than two months. Any specific thing you cannot do with .NET 6/8?